# Can not change timezone for kubernetes pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am trying to modify the config file of a pod to use local time, but it **show invalid** when saving. Do you know what's wrong ?

In volumeMounts section: I added below lines:

```
- mountPath: /etc/localtime
      name: tz-config
```

In volumes setion: I added below lines:

```
- name: tz-config
        hostPath:
          path: /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh
```

Here is my yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  .....
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: default-token-jgznd
      readOnly: true  
    - mountPath: /etc/localtime
      name: tz-config            
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  .....
  volumes:
  - name: default-token-jgznd
    secret:
      defaultMode: 420
      secretName: default-token-jgznd
  - name: tz-config
    hostPath:
      path: /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh
```

**UPDATE:** Below are error detail

```
# pods "hello-75fdf45c64-w7xm8" was not valid:
# * spec: Forbidden: pod updates may not change fields other than `spec.containers[*].image`, `spec.initContainers[*].image`, `spec.activeDeadlineSeconds` or `spec.tolerations` (only additions to existing tolerations)
#   core.PodSpec{
#       Volumes: []core.Volume{
#               {Name: "default-token-wcf8m", VolumeSource: core.VolumeSource{Secret: &core.SecretVolumeSource{SecretName: "default-token-wcf8m", DefaultMode: &420}}},
# -             {
# -                     Name: "tz-config",
# -                     VolumeSource: core.VolumeSource{
# -                             HostPath: &core.HostPathVolumeSource{Path: "/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh", Type: &""},
# -                     },
# -             },
#       },
#       InitContainers: nil,
```

Comment: Can you add your error logs as well !!

Comment: Using `hostPath:` can be unreliable: can you guarantee that every node in your cluster will have the same file in the same location?  I'd probably set container times to UTC, which would avoid this problem, but if you're going to pick a fixed other timezone like this, adding the required file to your image would be better.

Comment: Verify if image that You are using supports this method of time configuration. What is Your deployment image based on?

Comment: @PiotrMalec: My image based on OpenJDK:8. Is it support for time configuration ?

Comment: @DavidMaze: Please check my update about error logs

Comment: ...you created a bare Pod?  It's almost always better to create a Deployment.  The actual error message you're getting is that you can't change volume mounts on an existing Pod, so you have to delete the current Pod and create a new one.  A Deployment can be edited in place (and creates and deletes Pods for you).

Comment: @DavidMaze: No, I use Deployment, but how I can change the config of Deployment (where I can add my lines) ? I tried to edit pod directly by using command: kubectl edit pod xxxxx but not success

Comment: @taibc You update the pod spec aspect of the deployment file. That would be the `spec` section under `template`.

Comment: @Shawlz: I created deployment by using command: kubectl run transferFile --image=docker1:5000/transfer:1.0.0 --replicas=2 . So when I export my deployment to yaml file, the spec displayed as below, where can I update : spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 2
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: transferfile
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:

Comment: @DavidMaze : I tried to config timezone in my dockerfile as below, but the pod still got UTC timezone, ENV TZ=America/Los_Angeles
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

Comment: @taibc What you've provided isn't an entire yaml file for the deployment. Could you export the deployment file with `kubectl get deployment NAME -o yaml`. It will have a template section where which has a pod spec sub section.

Comment: @Shawlz: Great, it resolves my problem. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my problem by adding mountPath to the file deployment yaml as below. Many thanks @Shawlz for help:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
  creationTimestamp: "2020-02-14T15:59:50Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    run: hello
  name: hello
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "523908"
  selfLink: /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments/hello
  uid: 43196302-0176-4ce2-9d10-c8fefcc6c316
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: hello
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        run: hello
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: hello-microservice
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        name: hello
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
          - name: tz-config
            mountPath: /etc/localtime
      volumes:
        - name: tz-config
          hostPath:
            path: /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

it can be done simply by environment variable, example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: your-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: your-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: your-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: your-container
        image: nginx
        env:
        - name: TZ
          value: "Africa/Casablanca"
```